# SQL Subtract the values of two resultsets

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, subtraction

Is there an operator eavailable similar to UNION that will allow one query's resultset to be subtracted from another?

eg:

Result of a UNION

> 2 3 2 6 1 2 6 3 7
>
> 1 3 5 2 7 8 4 3 2

Result of potential subtraction operator

> 1 0 -3 4 -6 -6 2 0 5

Comment: Both are disjoint as `union` is set operator while`minus` is logical operator. Kindly share sample data and desired output in formatted text.

Comment: What's the expected result if the UNION returns 3 (or more) rows?

Comment: Edit had erroneously changed the examples from representing resultsets output from queries into columns.

Comment: @Matt do you need resultset being pivoted into columns?

Comment: @Artem no, someone had edited my question so that the rows were columns, so I edited it back. Thanks.

Comment: @Matt Let me know if the answer is useful

Answer (score 0):

You case is much simpler: just subtract one column from another

```
CREATE TABLE #A 
(
    col1 INT NOT NULL
    ,col2 INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #A (col1,col2)
    VALUES 
         (2,1)
        ,(3,3)
        ,(2,5)
        ,(6,2)
        ,(1,7)
        ,(2,8)
        ,(6,4)
        ,(3,3)
        ,(7,2)


SELECT (col1 - col2) AS result
FROM #A;

DROP TABLE #A;
```

**Original answer**

So if I understand you correctly you need to Subtract two one dimensional matrixes. `Sql Server` is not really the best tool to do such a math, but here is the example how you can achieve your goal. The idea is simple: introduce indexes (i,j) and join by them (you can skip j since you matrix is one-dimensional, the example works for two-dimensional arrays):

```
CREATE TABLE #A 
(
    element_value INT NOT NULL
    ,i INT NOT NULL
    ,j INT NOT NULL 
    ,PRIMARY KEY (i, j)
);

CREATE TABLE #B 
(
    element_value INT NOT NULL
    ,i INT NOT NULL
    ,j INT NOT NULL 
    ,PRIMARY KEY (i, j)
);

INSERT INTO #A (element_value,i,j)
    VALUES 
         (2,1,1)
        ,(3,1,2)
        ,(2,1,3)
        ,(6,1,4)
        ,(1,1,5)
        ,(2,1,6)
        ,(6,1,7)
        ,(3,1,8)
        ,(7,1,9)

INSERT INTO #B (element_value,i,j)
    VALUES 
         (1,1,1)
        ,(3,1,2)
        ,(5,1,3)
        ,(2,1,4)
        ,(7,1,5)
        ,(8,1,6)
        ,(4,1,7)
        ,(3,1,8)
        ,(2,1,9)    

SELECT (A.element_value - B.element_value) AS result
FROM #A AS A,#B AS B
WHERE A.i = B.i
    AND A.j = B.j;


DROP TABLE #A;            
DROP TABLE #B;
```